# Jquery switch on and off class on click

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to work out, on click function remove class `on` and add new class `off`. when I click on the div again I would like to add class `on` again and remove class `off` which is not happening. I am not sure what reason this is not working. But if alert it works.
Here is my code. and [Jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LEvM4/)

```
$(".on").bind('click',function() {
    $(this).removeClass('on').addClass('off');
    alert('Hello World');
})
$(".off").bind('click',function() {
    $(this).removeclass('off').addClass('on');
  alert('Hello World');
})
​
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`$(".on")` and `$(".off")` select elements currently in the DOM that match the selectors. So if you change the class of the element from `.on` to `.off` then it will still fire the `.on` event handler since that is what was bound to the element. You could use event delegation but I think `.toggleClass()` is probably a better implementation for you:

```
$(".on, .off").bind('click',function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('on off');
    alert('Hello World');
})
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LEvM4/1/

If you need to know which class is currently on the element you can check with `.hasClass()`:

```
$(".on, .off").bind('click',function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('on off');
    if ($(this).hasClass('on')) {
        alert('Hello World');
    } else {
        alert('Goodbye World');
    }
})
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LEvM4/2/

**A word about event delegation**. You can also bind to an element that is an ancestor of the element you want to bind to, and delegate the event handler to the descendant element:

```
$(document).delegate(".on", 'click', function() {
    $(this).addClass('off').removeClass('on');
    alert('Goodbye World');
}).delegate(".off", 'click', function() {
    $(this).addClass('on').removeClass('off');
    alert('Hello World');
})
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LEvM4/3/

A downside to event delegation is that when an event fires it requires more overhead. It's usually best to try and bind directly to an element if possible. Normally you use event delegation if an element is not currently present in the DOM but you want to bind to future instances of an element.

Some documentation for ya:

- `.on()`: http://api.jquery.com/on
- `.toggleClass()`: http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass
- `.hasClass()`: http://api.jquery.com/hasClass
- `.delegate()`: http://api.jquery.com/delegate

Comment: @user1193749 Yeah I think it's the simplest for you.

Answer (score 1):

This is much easier to code if you use a sort of live binding.  Consider

```
$('.on').live('click', function() {
  $(this).removeClass('on').addClass('off');
});
$('.off').live('click', function() {
  $(this).removeClass('off').addClass('on');
});
```

Comment: Notice that `.live()` is depreciated in favor of `.on()`: http://api.jquery.com/live (If you're using jQuery 1.4.2 up to 1.6.4 then `.delegate()` is preferred over `.live()`).

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check it.

```
$(".on").live('click',function() {
    $(this).removeClass('on').addClass('off');
})
$(".off").live('click',function() {
    $(this).removeclass('off').addClass('on');
})
```

Comment: Notice that `.live()` is depreciated in favor of `.on()`: http://api.jquery.com/live/ (If you're using jQuery 1.4.2 up to 1.6.4 then `.delegate()` is preferred over `.live()`).